# Are representations of finite groups unitary?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

I'm reading through a proof where $\Psi:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ and $\Phi:G\rightarrow GL(U)$ are representations of a finite group $G$, $a\in U$, $b\in V$, and $R:U\rightarrow V$ is a linear function. Then there is a line in the proof that goes:
$$\sum_{g\in G}\langle b,\Psi(g^{-1})R\Phi(g)a\rangle=\sum_{g\in G}\langle\Psi(g)b,R\Phi(g)a\rangle$$
I thought in general that for an operator $A$, $\langle b,Aa\rangle=\langle A^*b,a\rangle$, so it looks like that line is assuming $\Psi(g^{-1})=\Psi(g)^*$, i.e., $\Psi(g)$ is unitary.

I can see that since $g^n=e$ for some $n$, then $\Psi(g)^n=I$, so $det(\Psi(g))$ is an $n$th root of unity, but as far as I can tell that's not a sufficient condition to conclude that $\Psi(g)$ is unitary.

Does $\Psi(g)$ need to be unitary when $G$ is finite?

Comment: The point is that $U$ and $V$ are just (I am assuming real) vector spaces. You are free to equip them with any inner product you like. Then, by averaging, you can assume that these inner products are $G$-invariant.  In other words, any real (or complex) linear representation of a finite group is **unitarizable**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not.  For example, the representation of the $2$-element group $\{e,a\}$ by 
$$ 1 \to \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr},\ a \to \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 0 & -1\cr} $$